# When to convert IEnumerable to IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi, ienumerable, iasyncenumerable

In the .NET documentation for Controller Action Return Types ([doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#return-ienumerablet-or-iasyncenumerablet)), it shows this example on how to return a async response stream:

```
[HttpGet("asyncsale")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Product> GetOnSaleProductsAsync()
{
    var products = _productContext.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).AsAsyncEnumerable();

    await foreach (var product in products)
    {
        if (product.IsOnSale)
        {
            yield return product;
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, `_productContext.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).AsAsyncEnumerable()` converts the returned `IQueryable<Product>` into an `IAsyncEnumerable`. But the below example also works and streams the response asycnhronously.

```
[HttpGet("asyncsale")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Product> GetOnSaleProductsAsync()
{
    var products = _productContext.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name);

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        if (product.IsOnSale)
        {
            yield return product;
        }
    }

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

What's the reason for converting to `IAsyncEnumerable` first and doing `await` on the `foreach`? Is it simply for easier syntax or are there benefits of doing so?

Is there a benefit to converting any `IEnumerable` into `IAsyncEnumerable`, or only if the underlying `IEnumerable` is also streamable, for example through `yield`? If I have a list fully loaded into memory already, is it pointless to convert it into an `IAsyncEnumerable`?

Comment: In the second example none of that method is actually async. Is your question basically what the benefit of using async when performing IO is?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is: is this question really about `IAsyncEnumerable` or about asynchronous programming in general?

Comment: `IQueryable` implements too many interfaces, `.AsAsyncEnumerable` / `.AsEnumerable` just cast the result. Either way, the query will be executed when you start enumerating the results. Though these are bad examples, since you could filter the `IQueryable` and just return it.

Comment: Also `streaming != async`. Both examples process results as they are received. But the `async` version won't block your thread when the result is waiting for I/O.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama mostly about how the` await foreach` against the `IAsyncEnumerable` works. I left a comment below Theodor's answer to clarify, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` over an `IEnumerable<T>` is that the former is potentially more scalable, because it doesn't use a thread while is is enumerated. Instead of having a synchronous [`MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) method, it has an asynchronous [`MoveNextAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerator-1.movenextasync). This benefit becomes a moot point when the `MoveNextAsync` returns always an already completed `ValueTask<bool>` (`enumerator.MoveNextAsync().IsCompleted == true`), in which case you have just a synchronous enumeration masqueraded as asynchronous. There is no scalability benefit in this case. Which is exactly what's happening in the code shown in the question. You have the chassis of a Porsche, with a Trabant engine hidden under the hood.

If you want to obtain a deeper understanding of what's going on, you can enumerate the asynchronous sequence manually instead of the convenient `await foreach`, and collect debugging information regarding each step of the enumeration:

```
[HttpGet("asyncsale")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Product> GetOnSaleProductsAsync()
{
    var products = _productContext.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name).AsAsyncEnumerable();

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new();
    await using IAsyncEnumerator<Product> enumerator = products.GetAsyncEnumerator();
    while (true)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        ValueTask<bool> moveNextTask = enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
        TimeSpan elapsed1 = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        bool isCompleted = moveNextTask.IsCompleted;
        stopwatch.Restart();
        bool moved = await moveNextTask;
        TimeSpan elapsed2 = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine($"Create: {elapsed1}, Completed: {isCompleted}, Await: {elapsed2}");
        if (!moved) break;

        Product product = enumerator.Current;
        if (product.IsOnSale)
        {
            yield return product;
        }
    }
}
```

Most likely you'll discover that all `MoveNextAsync` operations are completed upon creation, at least some of them have a significant `elapsed1` value, and all of them have zero `elapsed2` values.

Comment: Does that mean whenever something is converted into an `IAsyncEnumerable`, it'll have asynchronous iterator? The async iteration is where I'm most confused about.
So when I iterate through a normal `List<int>` it's actually a blocking IO operation? But if I convert the `List<int>` into an `IAsyncEnumerable` the iteration will become a non-blocking async operation? My assumption was that to have an actual `async` iteration, the underlying `IEnumerable` data would have to be retrieved in an `async` way and has to be iterable without pulling in all the data once.

Comment: @roverred *So when I iterate through a normal List<int> it's actually a blocking IO operation?* << There is no I/O operation in this case. `List<int>` is already materialized view of a collection. In other words whenever you try to fetch the next item it will be already there. You don't have to perform any computation to produce the next value.

Comment: @roverred I added in the answer some code that might help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the reason for converting to IAsyncEnumerable first and doing await on the foreach?

If you want to take advantage of the async I/O. Whenever you fetch data from a database in case of `IEnumerable` it is a blocking operation. The calling thread (your `foreach`) have to wait until the database response arrives. While in case of `IAsyncEnumerable` the caller thread (your `await foreach`) can be assigned to a different request. So, it provides better scalability.

> Is it simply for easier syntax or are there benefits of doing so?

If the next item is (most likely) not available yet and you need to perform an I/O operation to fetch it then you can free up in the meanwhile the (otherwise blocking) caller thread.

> Is there a benefit to converting any IEnumerable into IAsyncEnumerable, or only if the underlying IEnumerable is also streamable, for example through yield?

In your particular example you have two `IAsyncEnumerable`s. Your datasource and your http response. You don't have to use both. It is absolutely okay to stream an `IEnumerable`. It is also okay to fetch asynchronously the datasource and return the result whenever all the data is available.

> If I have a list fully loaded into memory already, is it pointless to convert it into an IAsyncEnumerable?

Well, if you want to stream the response then yes it is not needed to asynchronously fetch the datasource.